# Google Chrome not detecting Headset and Web cam in Kali Linux

Tags: audio, kali-linux, chrome, camera

My current version of your Kali Linux is(`#cat /etc/issue`) **Kali GNU/Linux Rolling \n \l**

I am using google chrome from root user using this command `gksu -u ysr google-chrome` (there is another user called *'ysr'*).

Chrome Version is **50.0.2661.86 (64-bit)**.

My problem is that the google chrome doesn't recognize any of devices like headset,mic and webcam. 
But these are working perfectly in Iceweasel browser.

Thanks.

Comment: Why are you trying to change user to ysr to run google chrome? Do you also change user to ysr to run iceweasel?

Comment: I'm opening chrome as another user since I couldn't open it as root user, I've tried iceweasel in root user first, and now I tried as 'ysr' and it didn't recognize the devices.

Comment: Then I'm afraid the answer is "You using Linux wrong". I will make a retailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment's you using Linux wrong. That is why you are having this difficulty.

The great thing about Linux is that you can do so many things so many different ways. The one thing that everyone agrees on, however is that you should not do normal stuff as root. You should log in as a non-privileged user then become root (sudo or su or other ways) only to do administrative things (like package management).

So your essentially using Linux wrong and that's why your having such a hard time getting these apps to play along. You should create a normal user then log in as that user. Then attempt to run the applications in question.

Also you are going to need to add the normal user to the groups that can user the devices your trying to use. Perhaps try "plugdev" and "audio" groups. This will be different per system, so you will have to check and see what groups Kali uses.